# Log every WAN IP change

Tags: network, vpn

what would be the best way to log every WAN IP change on macOS?

there is some app like istats that would sent a notification on IP change, and I know there is some script that would log the WAN IP, but I want to make sure I don't lose any IP.

some time my IP can change within a sec (my macOS get an IP from IPsec but, before that iCloud relay would change the IP too and my gateway also connect my Mac to a WG server)

Comment: Can‘t you just run a script to log the IP address each second?

Comment: that was my initial thought was but I'm worried I could still miss some IP, I know it used to have a way to track it natively from the OS, and get the result through the consol but can't remember how

Comment: Tunnels and multiple routes make it hard to pin these down. Worse, your router and isp have much more control than the host os to make inspection and routing decisions for you.